# How to use utf8 encode with open pragma

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding

I have problem with `utf8::encode` when use pragma `use open qw(:std :utf8);`

**Example**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.16;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

use Data::Dumper;

my $word = "+банк";
say Dumper($word);
say utf8::is_utf8($word) ? 1 : 0;

utf8::encode($word);
say Dumper($word);
say utf8::is_utf8($word) ? 1 : 0;
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = "+\x{431}\x{430}\x{43d}\x{43a}";
1
$VAR1 = '+Ð±Ð°Ð½Ðº';
0
```

When I remove this pragma `use open qw(:std :utf8);`, everything is OK.

```
$VAR1 = "+\x{431}\x{430}\x{43d}\x{43a}";
1
$VAR1 = '+банк';
0
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Using `:std :utf8` adds an UTF-8 layer to `STDOUT`. Therefore the last `say` will try to encode `$word` once more..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to replace `utf8::encode($word);` with `use open qw(:std :utf8);`, you'll actually need to remove the `utf8::encode($word);`. In the version that doesn't work, you're encoding twice.

Answer (score 2):

utf8::encode is *not* what you want if you are going to print to a filehandle upon which perl expects to output utf8.

utf8::encode says take this string and give me a string where each character is a byte of the utf8 encoding of the input string.  This would normally be only done if you are then going to use that string in some way where perl *won't* be automatically converting to utf8 if necessary.

If you add a `say length($word);` after the encode, you will see that $word is 9 characters, not the original 5.