# How the open :utf8 pragma works in perl - in relation to CPAN modules?

Tags: perl

I'm already read thru the next:

- [Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html)
- [How differs the open pragma with different utf8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566460/how-differs-the-open-pragma-with-different-utf8)
- [How to use utf8 encode with open pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484066/how-to-use-utf8-encode-with-open-pragma)
- [Does the autodie-pragma have influence on the encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959384/does-the-autodie-pragma-have-influence-on-the-encoding)
- many others... (like: perlunicode perluniintro, perlunifaq, perlunitut)... ;(
- and of course tchrist's geniue answer [Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129)

but probably missed some BASIC points.

Using the

```
use open(:utf8);
```

Affects cpan modules too? E.g. when some CPAN module opens any file, it will be opened with `:utf8`?  Is this statement TRUE? (or the open pragma is only lexically scoped?) AFAIK - it affects modules too, but in "inconsistent" way.. (probably it is a problem of the modules).

Have the `open pragma` effect to `opendir`? - what i already tried - **no** - i still need extra `decode` on all filenames coming from `readdir` (in addition to NFC). So, IO::Dir is something different - what open pragma doesn't covers?

Affect the open pragma `sockets`, pipes too? (e.g. anything what is a sort of IO::Handle ?)

All (or most) CPAN modules knows when doing i/o how they need to do it (utf8 or lattin1 or raw?) (probably not, because a simple `autodie` doesn't works with the `open` pragma... :()

In many places I can read a similar rule: *Remember the canonical rule of Unicode: always encode/decode at the edges of your application.* This is nice rule - but the application edge mean: my own source code. CPAN modules are (usually) *behind the edge* too - not only the "outer world", like system or network...

From my experiance, 3/4 of the content my short scripts (what heavily uses CPAN)  contains: top declarations, and dozens of encode/decode/NFC for nearly everything...

E.g.:
Even logging utilities, need explicit encoding:

```
use Log::Any qw($log);
use Log::Any::Adapter ('File', 'file.log');
$log->error( encode('utf-8', "tökös"));
```

Even, when want add `tie` to my code, need replace every `$key` `$value` with encoded versions.

**Is this true, or i missed some really basic point in the all above doccu?**

Some CPAN module handling utf8 (inside) like, JSON::XS, YAML::XS, File::Slurp.. (altough never succeeded get correct "things" from YAML::XS, pure YAML and JSON::XS works without any problems...

For some modules exists "hacks" - like `DBIx::Class::ForceUTF8`, `Template::Stash::ForceUTF8`, `HTML::FillInForm::ForceUTF8` - and so, - what doesn't allow write correct application for "both" utf and non-utf world... ;(

Many CPAN modules doesn't calls internally the above 'hacked variants' -  (e.g. `HTML::FillInForm::ForceUTF8`) but only the simple-one, so it is impossible to use them correctly with utf8...  Others, silently fail.. ;(

Plack application doesn't handles utf8 *logging messages* without the annoying "Wide character...." ;( /modern perl :(/ and can continue ;(

From the above I "deducted" (probably wrongly) - than i **MUST** know and remember for every CPAN module how it is handling utf8 encoded strings and because nowhere is some "registry" - is is mostly trial/error based.

**So the main question is:**

While i remembering: *Here is no magic bullet*, **but is here some good way *how detect* and know "*utf8 ready CPAN modules*" what doesn't need special encode/decode before using them?**

If someone need to know, i'm using the next in my every script:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature qw(unicode_strings);
use charnames qw(:full);
use open(:utf8); #this sometimes is bad, so using only open qw(:std :utf8);
use Encode qw(encode decode);
use Unicode::Normalize qw(NFD NFC);
```

Hm.. just "discovered" the `utf8:all` perl module what replace the `readdir` with version doing decode.

Comment: Agree with your point of view, but this question looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281049/how-to-test-classify-cpan-modules-for-utf8-correctness . So: here is no regstry of utf8 correct modules and a 2/3 of CPAN simple doesn't care about other encodings as ascii (latin1) and counting _modern perl_ too - e.g. Moose doesn't allow utf8 method names.

Comment: [Recent versions](https://metacpan.org/changes/release/PJF/autodie-2.12) of [autodie](https://metacpan.org/module/autodie) **do** work with the [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) pragma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empahsis mine:

> The `open` pragma serves as one of the interfaces to declare default "layers" (also known as "disciplines") for all I/O. Any two-argument `open`, `readpipe` (aka `qx//`) and similar operators found within **the lexical scope** of this pragma will use the declared defaults. Even three-argument `open`s may be affected by this pragma when they don't specify IO layers in `MODE`.

So no, it doesn't effect any code in which the pragma isn't present. A handle opened within the scope of such a pragma won't lose its layers if passed to code outside of the scope of the pragma, though.

---

Tests to see what a module expects:

### Input

- Test 1

  - Have the input source return a string containing a code point in 80..FF and no code point above FF.
- Test 2

  - Have the input source return a string containing a code point above FF.

### Output

- Test 1

  - Output a string containing a code point in 80..FF and no code point above FF. Pass the string through `utf8::downgrade($_);` first.
- Test 2

  - Same as Test 1, but pass the string through `utf8::uprade($_);` first.
- Test 3

  - Output a string containing a code point above FF

Comment: Correct. You need to pass the expect type of handle. Should be documented, but I realise it's not always. If it's not, the module probably can't handle non-ASCII chars anyway.

Comment: In general, test. Test 1: Use a string containing a char in 80..FF and no character above FF. If you're testing an output, pass the string through `utf8::downgrade($_);` first. Test 2: Same as test1, but use `utf8::upgrade($_);`. Test 3: Use a string containing a char in above FF.

Comment: @Nemo, what about Perl itself? `open`, `opendir`, still work with the concept of file names are made of bytes.